# cleditor : Text format issue after copy and paste

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, cleditor

I am using [Cleditor](https://github.com/cleditor/cleditor) for my text input in a [jqGrid](http://jqgrid.com). Whenever I copy and paste any formatted data from some other file (say Microsoft Word) which has some words in bold format, and after pasting it when I make any other word in it as bold, then the word which was already bold, looses its bold format. I am getting this issue only in Chrome not in IE and Firefox....
Please suggest something.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the bold words. Is the bold word in the text you paste into the grid or do you make it bold after having pasted the text? And where is the "previously bold" word? Already in the grid? (Please answer these by editing your question, not by commenting)